# Illegal start of expression in Java AFTER ATTEMPTED SOLUTIONS

Tags: java

I am aware that this questions has been asked before, but I still face the same issue after trying to resolve it. Here's the code and an image:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Testing {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Greeting();
        AgeVerification();
        Calculator();
    }


        static void Greeting(){
            System.out.println("Hey. I'm Java, you are...?");
            Scanner getname = new Scanner(System.in);
            String name = getname.next();
            System.out.println("Nice to meet you "+name+".\n");
        }


        static void AgeVerification(){
            System.out.println("How old are you?");
            Scanner getage = new Scanner(System.in);
            Int age = getage.next();
            if(age => 18){
                System.out.println("Access granted, go ahead.");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Access denied, you're still a minor.");
            }
        }


        static void Calculator(){
            System.out.println("Now lets do some maths. Do you want to add, subtract, multiply, or divide?");
            Scanner getoperation = new Scanner(System.in);
            String operation = getoperation.next();
            if(operation == "add" | operation == "Add"){
                System.out.println("Which two numbers would you like to add? Enter them separately.");
            }
        }

}
```

https://ctrlv.cz/3JDJ

I originally had the three methods below the main listed as public, but removed the "public" attributes only to encounter the same issue. I am new to Java programming, and appreciate the help.

Comment: Which line are you getting the error? First of all, there is no type Int in Java. It should be either int (small i) or Integer type. Another thing, next() gives you a string type not integer which you have used in AgeVerification()

Comment: Hint: don't write 50 lines of code to then run the compiler. Just write a few lines (of which you think: this is "enough" to compile; like methods with empty bodies). Then run the compiler; fix problems; write more code. And study coding styleguides; method names start lowerCase(). Always. And for the next time: post your error messages. Dont expect other people to copy your code, run the compiler and then fix all the errors in there. Yes, that happens sometimes, but that is **not** how this site normally operates!

Comment: Why did you decide to remove the `public`? Does it have anything to do with the message you got? With the line that was marked very clearly in your image? You have a bad operator there, and several other problems. It's bad practice to just try to change things and see what sticks.

Comment: @GhostCat Ah yes sorry. The formatting has been edited since. I didn't see the beginning of `main` in the old version.

Comment: @GhostCat is telling you what's wrong -- you're using the wrong technique in creating code. If you can't use an IDE which will flag you immediately when you have a compilation error, then it is up to you to compile your code early and often, and not to add any new code until all compilation errors are fixed. And yeah, your error is the same as the thousands of similar questions on this topic out there, but the solution is to avoid the problem in the first place by doing what ghost cat tells you to.

Comment: @kjaquier Fine, then just delete your comment; as I did ;-)

Comment: Thanks everyone, appreciate the responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of problems with your code.

First, on this line:

```
Int age = getage.next();
```

To declare an integer, use the `int` type. Also, you probably want to use `nextInt()` instead of `next()`.

Next, this check is the wrong way around:

```
if(age => 18){
```

It should be `if (age >= 18){`.

And finally, in this line:

```
if(operation == "add" | operation == "Add"){
```

`|` is not doing what you think it is here, you should use `||`. 
As pointed out in the comments, you should check string equality using the `equals()` method.

```
    if(operation.equals("add") || operation.equals("Add")){
```

Finally, and this is just nitpicky, but if you wanted to you could change this if-statement to just check:

```
if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("add")) {
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: Not only should OP use `||` instead of `|`, strings should not be compared using `==`. Could also use `equalsIgnoreCase()` to eliminate the `||` altogether.

Comment: The use of `|` is weird, but it's perfectly legal to use it on `boolean`s, and the operator precedence is such that it actually works fine. `||` is not strictly necessary, just potentially faster because it short-circuits.

Answer (score 0):

You should change this:

```
Int age = getage.next();
```

to:

```
int age = getage.nextInt();
```

Case is important in Java, and while `int` is a built-in primitive type, `Int` has no meaning unless you define your own class called `Int` (which it seems you have not done). That will get rid of the "Illegal start of expression error". However, it will give you a different error because `Scanner#next()` returns a `String` and you want an integer value. Thus, you should be calling `nextInt()` instead of `next()`.

Also, as others have pointed out, the integer comparison operator you want to use in the next line is `>=` (think "greater than or equal"); there is no `=>` operator in Java.

Comment: next() returns String

Comment: @Kode - True, But at least the proposed change would get rid of the "Illegal start of expression" error. I'll update the answer to reflect your comment.

Comment: Actually, it's the `if(age => 18)` line that throws illegal start of expression.

Answer (score 0):

In AgeVerification(), change

```
Int age = getage.next();
```

to

```
int age = getage.nextInt();
```

Next there is no => opertor in java. So to compare the age change

```
if(age => 18){
  System.out.println("Access granted, go ahead.");
}
```

to

```
if(age >= 18){
      System.out.println("Access granted, go ahead.");
}
```

Also, you can " | " refers to bitwise OR. Whereas you want to check if the string equals add or Add. So change it to

```
if(operation.equalsIgnoreCase("add")){
   System.out.println("Which two numbers would you like to add? Enter them     separately.");
}
```

Comment: There may not be an `=>` operator, but there is `>=`. Right now, the code wouldn't grant access to anyone that is older than 18.